# Derivative with respect to 2 multiplied variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $$u = vw^2 + sv^n.$$ I want to calculate $\frac{du}{d(vw)}$. I calculated it as  $$\frac{du}{d(vw)}=w,$$ but using symbolab I got $$\frac{du}{d(vw)} = \frac{vw^2 + sv^n}{vw}$$ I pretty sure I am right, but if I am not I'd like an explanation.

The link for symbolab: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bd%5Cleft(vw%5Cright)%7D%5Cleft(vw%5E%7B2%7D%2Bsv%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cright)?or=input

Thanks!

Comment: my guy symbolab canceled the d in derivative so i didn't take one bro derivative

Comment: oh just saw that, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You need to say what you mean by $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d(vw)}$. That total derivative only makes sense if we know how everything else (in particular, $v$) depends on $vw$.

Comment: Result of symbolab is well-explained, it considers $d$ as factor, not differential operator. Your result is incorrect. Taking derivative by $vw$ suggests that $vw$ is independent variable than can change. If this variable can change, then we must know how $w$ and $v$ are changing with changing $vw$. First case: $v$ is constant, then $\frac{du}{d(vw)}=\frac{1}{v}\frac{du}{dw}=\frac{2vw}{v}=2w$. Second case: $w$ is constant, then $\frac{du}{d(vw)}=\frac{1}{w}\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{w^2+sn v^{n-1}}{w}=w+\frac{sn v^{n-1}}{w}$. Your result correspond to $w^2=nsv^{n-1}$, which is very special case.

Comment: What you have stated so far is  not enough information to compute this.

Comment: Suppose $v=w=1$, so $vw=1$. Then $u=1+s$. Now suppose $v=2,w=\frac12$. We still have $vw=1$ but $u$ has changed. Now $u=\frac12+2^ns$. So even with zero change in $vw$ there is change in $u$. Therefore $\frac{du}{d(vw)}$ doesn't make sense. It could make sense if there is some hidden relationship between $v$ and $w$ that rules out my freedom to choose $v$ and $w$ independently.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether you view $w$ as a constant or whether you view $v$ as a constant when you vary $x \equiv vw$.  If you hold $w$ constant, then you have
$$
u = xw + sx^n/w^n \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)_w = w + n \frac{s x^{n-1}}{w^n} = w + n s \frac{v^{n-1}}{w}
$$
but if you hold $v$ constant then you have
$$
u = \frac{x^2}{v} + sv^n = \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)_v = \frac{2x}{v} = 2w.
$$
As you can see, the result depends on which variable you fix as constant when you take the derivative.  This feature of partial derivatives is (in my opinion) not really emphasized enough in multi-variable calculus courses.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on whether $dvdw>0$ ($v$ and $w$ are both increasing or decreasing) or $dvdw<0$ (either $v$ or $w$ is increasing and the other is decreasing) or $dx=0$ where $x\in \{v,w\}$ (only either $v$ or $w$ is not changing; $du/d(vw)$ is undefined if $dv=0 \wedge dw=0$).
\begin{eqnarray}
dvdw&>&0\\
\dfrac{du}{d(vw)}&=&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{u(v-h,w-h)-u(v,w)}{(v-h)(w-h)-vw}}\\
&=&\lim_{-h\to 0}{\dfrac{u(v-h,w-h)-u(v,w)}{(v-h)(w-h)-vw}}\\
&\equiv&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{u(v+h,w+h)-u(v,w)}{(v+h)(w+h)-vw}}\\
&=&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{(v+h)(w+h)^2+s(v+h)^n-vw^2-sv^n}{(v+h)(w+h)-vw}}\\
&=&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{(v+h)(w^2+2wh+h^2)-vw^2+s(v+h)^n-sv^n}{h(v+w+h)}}\\
&=&{\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{h(v+h)(2w+h)+hw^2}{h(v+w+h)}}+{s\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{(v+h)^n-v^n}{h(v+w+h)}}}}\\
(v+h)^n&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}v^{n-k}h^k}\\
&=&v^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\dfrac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-1-k)!}v^{n-1-k}h^{k+1}}\\
\dfrac{du}{d(vw)}&=&{\dfrac{2vw+w^2}{v+w}+s\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{1}{v+w+h}}\lim_{h\to 0}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\dfrac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-1-k)!}v^{n-k-1}h^k}}}\\
&=&\dfrac{2vw+w^2}{v+w}+\dfrac{s}{v+w}\lim_{h\to 0}{(nv^{n-1}+O(h))}\\
&=&\dfrac{w^2+snv^{n-1}+2vw}{w+v}\\
dvdw&<&0\\
\dfrac{du}{d(vw)}&=&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{u(v-h,w+h)-u(v,w)}{(v-h)(w+h)-vw}}\\
&=&\lim_{-h\to 0}{\dfrac{u(v-h,w+h)-u(v,w)}{(v-h)(w+h)-vw}}\\
&\equiv&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{u(v+h,w-h)-u(v,w)}{(v+h)(w-h)-vw}}\\
&=&{\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{h(v+h)(h-2w)+hw^2}{h(w-v-h)}}+s\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{1}{w-v-h}}\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{(v+h)^n-v^n}{h}}}\\
&=&\dfrac{w^2+snv^{n-1}-2vw}{w-v}\\
dv&=&0\\
\dfrac{du}{d(vw)}&=&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{u(v,w+h)-u(v,w)}{v(w+h)-vw}}\\
&=&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{v(w+h)^2-vw^2+sv^n-sv^n}{vh}}\\
&=&2w\\
&=&\dfrac{2vw}{v}\\
dw&=&0\\
\dfrac{du}{d(vw)}&=&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{u(v+h,w)-u(v,w)}{(v+h)w-vw}}\\
&=&\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{(v+h)w^2-vw^2+s(v+h)^n-sv^n}{wh}}\\
&=&\dfrac{w^2+snv^{n-1}}{w}\\
\end{eqnarray}
We can notice that if we define:
$$
\gamma_{x\in \{v,w\}} :=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if}& dx=0\\
-1 &\text{if}& dvdw<0\\
&& dvdw>0\wedge x=w\\
1 &\text{if}& dvdw>0\wedge x=v
\end{cases}\\
$$
We get:
$$
\dfrac{du}{d(vw)}=\dfrac{\gamma_v2vw-\gamma_w(w^2+snv^{n-1})}{\gamma_vv-\gamma_ww}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=vw^2+sv^n.$

Assume that, $x=vw$, this implies that $sv^n=sx^nw^{-n}$ and $\dfrac{dw}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{dx}{dw}}=\dfrac{1}{v}$. Then we can write $u$ as:

$u=xw + sx^nw^{-n}$, now differentiate using product rule to have

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
   \dfrac{du}{d(vw)}&=\dfrac{du}{dx}\\
     &=w\dfrac{dx}{dx}+x\dfrac{dw}{dx} + sw^{-n}\dfrac{dx^n}{dx} + sx^n\dfrac{dw^{-n}}{dx}\\
     &=w +x\dfrac{1}{v} + nsw^{-n}x^{n-1} -nsx^nw^{-n-1}\dfrac{dw}{dx}\\
     &=w +vw\dfrac{1}{v} + nsw^{-n}(vw)^{n-1} -ns(vw)^nw^{-n-1}\dfrac{1}{v}\\
     &=w + w + nsw^{-1}v^{n-1} -nsv^{n-1}w^{-1}\\
     &=2w
  \end{split}
 \end{equation*}